# closest() - IE issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am trying to fetch an element with the title (since the ID changes dynamically) and hide the td.
While the below works in Chrome , I get an err in IE as -

> Object doesn't support property or method 'closest'

```
document.querySelector('[title="myName"]').closest("td") = true;
```

Comment: so what could i use to get the element by title? Looks like element.closest works in IE

Comment: As you've tagged this [jquery] (I added the [javascript] tag as there was no jquery in the question), use `$("[title="myName"]').closest("td").hide();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> .closest() works in Chrome, but I get an error in IE

`.closest()` native/vanilla javascript method is not supported in IE.

See:

http://caniuse.com/#search=closest

[developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

This is what jquery was originally written for - cross-browser support without needing to lookup support details.

```
$('[title="myName"]').closest("td").hide();
```

Comment: .closest("td").previousElementSibling.hidden = false; How could i get the prev element  as this doesnt work in IE.

Comment: Use `.prev()` `$('[title="myName"]').closest("td").prev().show();` (.show/.hide depending)